Strange behaviour of Fuseki with SPARQL
Given (almost) any dataset in a Fuseki triple store I get very strange behaviour. For this example to work the dataset needs at least one rdf triple where the predicate is rdfs:comment. I need this specific pattern for a SPARQL query that needs to work on both Grapdb and Fuseki.
The query is the following:
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT *
{
    {
        SELECT 
            (MAX(?number) AS ?number2)
        {
           ?something rdfs:comment ?comment .
            BIND(23 AS ?number)
        }
    }
    {
        BIND("option 1" AS ?option)
        BIND(?number2 AS ?test)
    } UNION {
        BIND("option 2" AS ?option)
        BIND(?number2/10 AS ?test)
    }
}

The correct result should be



number2
option
test




23
option 1
23


23
option 2
2.3



This works both on Fuseki and GraphDB.
strange behaviour 1
When you delete the line ?something rdfs:comment ?comment . the variable ?test does not get bound anymore on Fuseki. Still gets bound correctly in GraphDB.
strange behaviour 2
When you replace (MAX(?number) AS ?number2) by (23 AS ?number2) the same thing happens. ?test does not get bound anymore on Fuseki. Still gets bound correctly in GraphDB. Ofcourse the number of lines that is returned in this case equals the number of triples with the predicate rdfs:label, times two. Which is irrelevant to the issue.
Without the mentioned dataset that returns at least a triple (I used rdfs:comment, any other line would work, as long as you get a result) Fuseki never binds anything to ?test. No clue why.
question
Anybody has a suggestion on how to structure the query so I can get the same results on Fuseki and GraphDB. I need a subquery and than a UNION query that is able to use the result of that subquery. I'm calling it a subquery because in SPARQL it needs to be a level 'deeper' since the deeper level gets executed first.

I'd say the  binding of ?number2 you're getting from the subquery is not in the scope of the evaluation of the UNION pattern when doing a BIND inside there. Evaluation is molstly bottom-up, so the subquery and the union pattern are being evaluated, then their result being joined.

Agreed, but sometimes it is and sometimes it is not in scope, depending on the 'random' line mentioned in strange behaviour 1 and on the use of MAX mentioned in strange behaviour 2. Anyway since the binding of ?number2 is a level deeper, it should be in the scope of the UNION part always?

Which version of Fuseki?

?number2 is not in scope when the UNION is evaluated.  It is put into the results from the join of the subSelect and the already-evaluated UNION. Scoping is no based on levels - it's by subtree.
You can explore the query algebra at https://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html

Thanks for that insight @AndyS. I'll look into that. Fuseki version is 5.1.0
